# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException while rendering a JSF view

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: String index out of range: -655830221
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
        at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:152)
        at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.Invokable.invoke(Invokable.java:38)
        at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.runServlet(HttpHandlerImpl.java:457)
        at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.server.HttpHandlerImpl.handleRequest(HttpHandlerImpl.java:210)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:441)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.RequestAnalizer.startServlet(RequestAnalizer.java:430)
        at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.DSRWebContainerFilter.process(DSRWebContainerFilter.java:38)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ServletSelector.process(ServletSelector.java:81)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.servlets_jsp.filters.ApplicationSelector.process(ApplicationSelector.java:278)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.WebContainerInvoker.process(WebContainerInvoker.java:81)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.ResponseLogWriter.process(ResponseLogWriter.java:60)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.HostFilter.process(HostFilter.java:9)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DefineHostFilter.process(DefineHostFilter.java:27)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MonitoringFilter.process(MonitoringFilter.java:29)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.SessionSizeFilter.process(SessionSizeFilter.java:26)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.MemoryStatisticFilter.process(MemoryStatisticFilter.java:57)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.filters.DSRHttpFilter.process(DSRHttpFilter.java:43)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.ServerFilter.process(ServerFilter.java:12)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.chain.AbstractChain.process(AbstractChain.java:78)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor.chainedRequest(Processor.java:475)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.Processor$FCAProcessorThread.process(Processor.java:269)
        at com.sap.engine.services.httpserver.server.rcm.RequestProcessorThread.run(RequestProcessorThread.java:56)
        at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:122)
        at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.Executable.run(Executable.java:101)
        at com.sap.engine.core.thread.execution.CentralExecutor$SingleThread.run(CentralExecutor.java:328)
    Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -655830221
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1979)
        at java.lang.String.trim(String.java:2747)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.buildTypeArrayFromString(RenderKitUtils.java:867)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils.determineContentType(RenderKitUtils.java:563)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java:260)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:992)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:382)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
        ... 39 more
```

Comment: "StringIndexOutOfBoundException" everything is in the name ! You try to access to a content which is out of the limit of the String

Comment: This problem is occuring randomly. Its a moving target and the logs don't show my application file name. It's all standard files.

Comment: what JRE version you are using?

Comment: most likely you're misusing a component (probably by not defining a required attribute). Do you have nested `<h:form/>`s anywhere on that page? Paste the page code here. You might have to go by the process of  elimination to find the offending component